# Link to jump to a position further down in the same page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out how to get a tag on my page so when I click it, it jumps to another section on the same page.
I have a link in my show page with:

```
<li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem" style="background:#39AFBF">
     <a href="#stats" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">   
       <span>impact</span></a>
  </li>
```

I then have a section lower down on the same page:

```
  <section class="counter index section parallax-bg"  id="stats" data-background="<%= image_path 'testimonial.jpg' %>">
```

But when I save this, I get an error that says:

```
Couldn't find Profile with 'id'=stats
```

The same is problem arises with this one:

```
<li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem" style="background:#009CB2">
                     <a href="#feedback" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
                     <span>feedback</span></a>
                  </li>

<section class="section index parallax-bg testimonial" id="feedback" data-background="<%= image_path 'webre.png', :style=>"background-repeat: repeat !important; background-size: inherit !important;" %>">
```

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if people left messages explaining why they down vote questions. It might be a simple problem for others but I've been struggling to figure this out all day (8 hours and counting). I don't learn anything from a down vote... and whatever it is that caused someone to vote, doesnt get addressed by a vote without a reason or comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're using is an *anchor* link, and when *anchors* links are clicked, the browser is supposed to simply jump to the anchor in the currently loaded page.

However, in your case, it seems to be calling the URI `/profile/:id` with `:id` set to `stats`.

**Are you sure** that the `href` is correctly set to `#stats`, and not simply `stats`, because if it's set to the latter, then the link will point to `/profile/stats` (clicking on this will cause a request to be sent to server), instead of `/profile/SOME_ID#stats` (which will not cause a request; the browser will jump to anchor on current page). The latter is what should be happening, but it isn't. Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Hi Hari. I'm sure that I have the # in the a link. I can't understand why its not working

Comment: Hi Hari, I've changed nothing - just waited a while before refreshing the page. It works now. I'm wondering if that's because it takes time to refresh (outside of my control). I'm only working in the local host, but I can't think what else would cause this problem

Comment: Sounds like you were running old code, then. Might want to make sure that your `development.rb` server settings are up to date.